# Is it possible to use "dkim" at "smtp2go" for a domain set up to work under "Google Apps for Work"?

Tags: google-apps-for-work

Is it possible to use [dkim custom signatures](http://support.smtp2go.com/entries/23451641-Custom-DKIM-signatures) at [smtp2go](https://app.smtp2go.com/settings/dkim/) for a domain set up to work under "Google Apps for Work"?